# java.lang.NullPointerException in jsp

Tags: java, json, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Hi all I am a fresher in java and jsp and honestly I dont have knowledge of json. but I have some requirement that I have to pull the data from database and display on jsp page. but the criteria is that I have to use  Bootstrap Data Table why I am using this because it provide lot of flexibility like Pagination Filtering Sorting Multi-column sorting Individual column filter.
I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in my `jsp`
can any body tell me why am I getting this error.
This is my jsp page

```
dataTable.jsp

<%@page import="org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ page import ="java.util.*" %>
  <%--  <%@ page import="com.varun.DataBase"%> --%>
   <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%--    <%@ page import="org.json.*"%> --%>
   <%@ page import ="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>


 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DataTable</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Lets display the data from database using dataTabel</h1>

<%

String[] cols = { "id","engine", "browser", "platform", "version", "grade" };
String table = "ajax";

JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();


int amount = 10;
int start = 0;
int echo = 0;
int col = 0;

int  id=0;
String engine = "";
String browser = "";
String platform = "";
String version = "";
String grade = "";



String dir = "asc";
String sStart = request.getParameter("iDisplayStart");
String sAmount = request.getParameter("iDisplayLength");
String sEcho = request.getParameter("sEcho");
String sCol = request.getParameter("iSortCol_0");
String sdir = request.getParameter("sSortDir_0");

engine = request.getParameter("sSearch_0");
browser = request.getParameter("sSearch_1");
platform = request.getParameter("sSearch_2");
version = request.getParameter("sSearch_3");
grade = request.getParameter("sSearch_4");


List<String> sArray = new ArrayList<String>();
if (!engine.equals("")) {
    String sEngine = " engine like '%" + engine + "%'";
    sArray.add(sEngine);
    //or combine the above two steps as:
    //sArray.add(" engine like '%" + engine + "%'");
    //the same as followings
}

if (!browser.equals("")) {
    String sBrowser = " browser like '%" + browser + "%'";
    sArray.add(sBrowser);
}
if (!platform.equals("")) {
    String sPlatform = " platform like '%" + platform + "%'";
    sArray.add(sPlatform);
}
if (!version.equals("")) {
    String sVersion = " version like '%" + version + "%'";
    sArray.add(sVersion);
}
if (!grade.equals("")) {
    String sGrade = " grade like '%" + grade + "%'";
    sArray.add(sGrade);
}

String individualSearch = "";
if(sArray.size()==1){
    individualSearch = sArray.get(0);
}else if(sArray.size()>1){
    for(int i=0;i<sArray.size()-1;i++){
        individualSearch += sArray.get(i)+ " and ";
    }
    individualSearch += sArray.get(sArray.size()-1);
}


if (sStart != null) {
    start = Integer.parseInt(sStart);
    if (start < 0)
        start = 0;
}
if (sAmount != null) {
    amount = Integer.parseInt(sAmount);
    if (amount < 10 || amount > 100)
        amount = 10;
}
if (sEcho != null) {
    echo = Integer.parseInt(sEcho);
}
if (sCol != null) {
    col = Integer.parseInt(sCol);
    if (col < 0 || col > 5)
        col = 0;
}
if (sdir != null) {
    if (!sdir.equals("asc"))
        dir = "desc";
}


String colName = cols[col];
int total = 0;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","system","admin");
try {
    String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM "+table;
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        total = rs.getInt("count(*)");
    }
}catch(Exception e){

}
int totalAfterFilter = total;
//result.put("sEcho",echo);

try {
    String searchSQL = "";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table;
    String searchTerm = request.getParameter("sSearch");
    String globeSearch =  " where (engine like '%"+searchTerm+"%'"
                            + " or browser like '%"+searchTerm+"%'"
                            + " or platform like '%"+searchTerm+"%'"
                            + " or version like '%"+searchTerm+"%'"
                            + " or grade like '%"+searchTerm+"%')";
    if(searchTerm!=""&&individualSearch!=""){
        searchSQL = globeSearch + " and " + individualSearch;
    }
    else if(individualSearch!=""){
        searchSQL = " where " + individualSearch;
    }else if(searchTerm!=""){
        searchSQL=globeSearch;
    }
    sql += searchSQL;
    sql += " order by " + colName + " " + dir;
    sql += " limit " + start + ", " + amount;

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
       // JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
        net.sf.json.JSONArray ja = new net.sf.json.JSONArray(); 

        ja.add(rs.getInt("id"));
        ja.add(rs.getString("engine"));
        ja.add(rs.getString("browser"));
        ja.add(rs.getString("platform"));
        ja.add(rs.getString("version"));
        ja.add(rs.getString("grade"));
        arr.add(ja); 
    } 
    String sql2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM "+table;
    if (searchTerm != "") {
        sql2 += searchSQL;
        PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
        ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
        if (rs2.next()) {
            totalAfterFilter = rs2.getInt("count(*)");
        }
    }
    result.put("iTotalRecords", total);
    result.put("iTotalDisplayRecords", totalAfterFilter);
    result.put("aaData", arr);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    out.print(result);
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Stack Trace

```
11:26:50,224 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.dataTable_jsp._jspService(dataTable_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you point to line number `114`

Comment: Go to translated Servlet `dataTable_jsp.java` of this jsp file and look at line no 114. It will  be under `work` folder if you are running it via tomcat server.

Comment: May be use this `http://jquerygrid.net/`

Comment: @singhakash line no 114 says: String dir - dataTable._jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the answer of Ajil Mohan prevent the error to appear, it means that you have no value in your ParametersMap.

```
engine = request.getParameter("sSearch_0");
browser = request.getParameter("sSearch_1");
platform = request.getParameter("sSearch_2");
version = request.getParameter("sSearch_3");
grade = request.getParameter("sSearch_4");
```

These lines just get the data in the Parameter map of your request. If the given is not in the map it returns null (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). 
This map is created when you send the POST request on the previous page with the data contained in your form. Your input field has to be set with the name you give to the getParameter method.

If you don't have previous page with a form then you may want to send data from server to JSP. If you use Servlet then you should use the request AttributeMap.

```
public class BasicTotoServlet extends HttpServlet {
 /**
  * Manage GET HTTP Request
  */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String data = getData();
        request.setAttibute("sSearch_0", data)
    }
}
```

Then in your JSP :

```
engine = request.getAttribute("sSearch_0");
```

I hope I was clear enough. 
Ask for precision if needed

EDIT : 
Here is what I understand.

You arrive on your JSP and you get several Parameter from the previous page's form. This form may not give to you all the information, that is why you get a NPE on this

```
engine = request.getParameter("sSearch_0");
engine.equals("")
```

To solve this as told you Ajil Mohan, just turn the equals the other way round, so that if engine is NULL you have no problem

```
"".equals(engine);
```

As "" is never null you'll never get NPE.

Now you don't have any data in you table. Why? If I'm correct you create a SQL Query by concatenating several data. `searchSQL = globeSearch + " and " + individualSearch;`

`individualSearch` is the result of concatenating your Parameters but what if they're null?

```
if (!"".equals(browser)) {
    String sBrowser = " browser like '%" + browser + "%'";
    sArray.add(sBrowser);
}
```

In this code, if browser is null (as we saw earlier it can be), you will add the String `" browser like '%null%'"` to you query with the and key word. I'm not sure there will be any browser with "null" in its name.

You better put this test :

```
if (!"".equals(browser) && browser != null) {
    String sBrowser = " browser like '%" + browser + "%'";
    sArray.add(sBrowser);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not using controller class. from the jsp it self I am trying to send request. if possible please provide me the  precision

Comment: What is your workflow at the moment. Do you have a form that you validate and come to dataTable.jsp ? Or do you come on dataTable.jsp and get data from database to feed your table?
Where does the sSearch_0 value come from?

Comment: I want to use data table to display data from db so I followed this  link https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp   I have done the same

Comment: By the way, you should look at HTML 5 which will become the standard. JSP is quite an old technology now and there are lots of ways to improve what you want to do. Maybe you should consider having a controller to get your data then then forward the data to the JSP. Then in the JSP you can use "[Expression language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html)" (EL) to create your HTML page. [Here is an example in French](http://www.rpresle.totoandco.eu/atelier-creation-servlet-et-jsp-agrementee-de-jstl/) but code block are in English. Don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a jsp file its very difficult to debug. Here you are getting a NullPointerExceotion . From your code we can see that some places where NullPointerException would occur.

For Eg:-
You are getting parameter from "sSearch_0".
engine = request.getParameter("sSearch_0");

Just imagine, if its a null value.

Then following code will produce a nullpointer exception.

if (!engine.equals(""))

So it is always safe to check as follows,
if(!" ".equals(engine)) ...

In this way you wont get null pointer exception even if engine has a null value.

This may not be the issue, but I wish to mention it.

Comment: As you suggested the error are gone. but I am not getting the value . I am just getting the  <h1>Lets display the data from database using dataTabel</h1> any idea??

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using something like Google gson in your controller to automatically produce json from a model class? It could reduce the string manipulation inside your jsp.

A more common pattern would be to expose this information from a restful api which is consumed by an ajax call on the front end.

Java Jersey in combination with gson or Jackson could achieve a lot of this functionality for you

Comment: I do not have controller, Since I am totally new with json i was just trying to display the data from Table to jsp using Bootstrap Data Table . once I am able to figure it. out I will implement with controller. can you please help me this.